# Mathematical modeling stackexchange?

Tags: discussion, area51

I've seen several questions on MSE and MO asking about math models, and it seems that the community is often unable to help as much as they would like. This has been discussed before: [Mathematical Modeling and Applied Mathematics Question Policy](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214/mathematical-modeling-and-applied-mathematics-question-policy)

I think a mathematical modeling SE site would be worthwhile for the following reasons:

1. Very different user base. Algebraic geometry, set theory and general topology are threeof the most popular topics on both websites, and they have a very pure-math slanted user base. A math modeling SE would be designed for all the experts in government, industry, finance, etc. to share tips with more of an SO feel than MO.
2. Applied math questions here attract less attention and, often, downvotes.
3. The types of questions asked would be very different. Almost no homework questions would make sense on a math modeling SE, and answers would be based on individuals experience with successful models in the past.

This would be a website for experts in a technical area, and I feel it would make a good SE site without detracting from MsE or MO in any way.

What are your thoughts? Why would it or wouldn't it work?

**Edit** see also this post from SciComp SE: https://scicomp.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/348/computational-modelling-vs-mathematical-modelling

Comment: Related: http://abstrusegoose.com/105 :-)

Comment: There's that scientific computing SE, that is kind of similar.

Comment: @AlexanderGruber Do you mean [Computational Science](http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: Are there enough people on SE to answer questions in the site you propose?

Comment: @GitGud I think the idea is that we precisely want sites that cater to new individuals.

Comment: @BrianRushton I didn't realise that the creation of a new site brought as many answerers as it did questioners (in relative proportion). If that's the case, then I think a site like that is in order as such questions aren't well received here.

Comment: @GitGud it definitely seems like the goal is to attract experts, from feedback I've got on Area51. Finding experts on the other hand...

Comment: @BrianRushton: in addition to asking here, you should also float the idea on [Area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/), giving the reasons you gave above.

Comment: I've added ([meta-tag:area51]) tag, since the post seems to be about new site proposal. (Feel free to remove the tag, if you think it does not fit.)

Comment: @WillieWong Let me check with the comp sci people first to make sure it doesnt immediately get closed as a duplicate.

Comment: Actually, this post makes me feel I can go forward: http://meta.scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/348/computational-modelling-vs-mathematical-modelling

Answer (score 10):

As suggested, this proposal has been listed on Area51 SE for possible creation, with a few sample questions taken from other SE sites (trying to get ones which were labelled off-topic for the site they were in): http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/57490/mathematical-modeling?referrer=B5TWQ70QNWlDGxDR-o9vQA2. As usual, SE members can add questions they would like to see and vote on others' questions.

As I am not employed in mathematical modeling, I would appreciate it if someone with more expertise in the area would post some sample questions that an actual expert might ask, and suggest any edits to the description.

Answer (score 1):

Math.StackExchange is good for pure math questions or questions of a somewhat applied nature.  However there are several other StachExchanges which are of a highly quantitative nature.

- **[Scientific Computing](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/)**

  - Often good for PDE or numerical algorithms
  - Approxmation Theory
- **[Computer Science](https://cs.stackexchange.com/)**

  - Good for questions about searching and sorting or graph theory
  - See also **[Theoretical Computer Science](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/)**
- **[Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/)**

  - when your question is about math interfacing with empirical data
  - statistics, machine learning, probability theory
- **[Tex StackExchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/)**

  - questions specifically about LaTeX
- **[Quantitative Finance](https://quant.stackexchange.com/)**

  - specifically about derivative securities, arbitrage, etc.
- **[Signal Processing](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/)**

  - still in beta
- **[Cryptography](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/)**

  - if your question doesn't fit into CS or Theoretical CS

And many others.  If your question doesn't strictly fit into the topics usually covered by MathOverflow or here, you can try to think laterally and pose it on one of the other sites.  In some cases their domain-specific knowledge is helpful but in other cases, it can hide the big picture.