# Weaknesses of Mathematics SE — Not knowing where some difficulties lie

Tags: discussion

I think it would be useful to start a series of posts on the weaknesses of Mathematics SE for diagnosis precedes remedy.

In my humble opinion, one major weakness of Mathematics SE is that many users — including many high-reputation ones — simply do not quite know where some difficulties lie. I have worked with former mathematicians in industry and talking to them about mathematics is almost gauche, as once a real-world (non-mathematical) problem has been translated to a mathematical problem, with much exaggeration, it is either *trivial* or *intractable*.  The difficulties lie in acquiring the domain knowledge required to translate the real-world problem to a mathematical problem in an artful and tasteful manner.

On Mathematics SE, one sometimes reads potentially interesting embryonic questions written by people without much mathematical training, say, on some problem from biology or engineering. If I perceive that the OP is asking the question in good faith, I often try to push the OP towards improvement of the question by asking several questions in the comment section and then editing the question in order to improve it via incorporation of the information provided by the OP in the comment section.  Unfortunately, these questions are often closed — say, due to lack of clarity — **before** the seedling question has sprouted into a budding question that is ready to bloom.  Why?  An entire class of questions is being "uprooted" **before** one even has a chance to assess whether it's a flower or a weed.  Why not be a bit more patient?

In my humble opinion, users of Mathematics SE should consider reading [Bernard Beauzamy](https://www.mathgenealogy.org/id.php?id=89101)'s [Real life mathematics](https://www.maths.tcd.ie/pub/ims/bull48/M4801.pdf) (2001).

---

Related:

- [Mathematical Modeling and Applied Mathematics Question Policy](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/214/339790)

Comment: I appreciate your intentions, but do close some such questions. My thought process is as follows (1) People can continue to converse in the comments and (like I said in the previous question) copy useful comments of OP into the question, each time sending the question into the reopen queue. I assume that people will not shun conversation when the question is closed. (2) Not everyone wants to read developing questions, users want to be reading ready-made ones as well. Answering those properly respects the users that take the time to formulate well written questions.

Comment: @SarveshRavichandranIyer I don't disagree.  I am fine with closing embryonic questions provided that they are opened once they have reached a certain level of maturity.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo ... I see the point.  The process goes: close the question, work on it until it is satisfactory, then re-open.  An impediment to this approach is the phenomenon of over-eager deleters, who propose deletion of a question too soon.

Comment: @GEdgar I wholeheartedly agree.

Comment: If a question has been closed, you could post a new version of it, citing the original and repairing any defects that might have kept the original from being properly appreciated.  That way, the desirable content survives.

Comment: @lulu, if a question is badly written, it may be impossible for us to figure out what repairs to make; it may be impossible for us to know what OP was trying to ask. Often only OP can tell us that.

Comment: @GerryMyerson  Well...if a question is that poorly written, then I wouldn't think there was any valuable content worth preserving.  I'm thinking about the (rare?) situation in which there is a good idea inside the question...something worth extracting.

Comment: @lulu It can be quite hard to determine whether a question coming from the real world has any mathematical value or not.

Comment: I'm thinking of an example from years back...the details aren't important.  The very terse question was something about counting words made from a fixed alphabet. But as people pointed out the routine answers, the OP kept remembering rules that needed to be satisfied.  The question was hopeless, as the rules kept changing...but there was a core idea.  There were some flat laws, implied by Chemistry, and there were some statistical laws observed in nature.  I can see some very strong questions along these lines, though the actual post wasn't very useful.

Comment: @GEdgar I wish that model worked better in practice. But closed questions are rarely reopened, whether or not they are improved, and closure is a death sentence for the post.  I often wonder if it would work better if the original close voters received a notification when the post was edited, inviting them to take another look.

Comment: @MJD That is an interesting suggestion. I posted a [question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/388188/343170) on Meta about it.

Comment: I think most would agree that patiently guiding an OP through the process of improving their question is better than closing it. It's just a question of scale. With hundreds of questions a day, some will have to be closed without further guidance than the closure message and linked FAQs. That doesn't prevent you from giving individual attention when you do see potential.

Comment: It does actually prevent me from doing that, because questions are sometimes closed and deleted while the process is incomplete. Then my time is wasted. And because I don't want to waste my time that way, I am more reluctant to begin the process than I wouldbe if every my interactions weren't under threat of being cut short.

Comment: I think there's something to this question, but I think the discussion would be a _whole_ lot more fruitful if specific examples were provided and discussed.

Comment: @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC That is not so easy, as, in my experience, most questions of this class are either abandoned by the OP (which is not Mathematics SE's fault) or closed / deleted before a satisfactory state of maturity is reached.  Often, a satisfactory state of maturity is arguably unreachable.

Comment: Well, prompted by your post here, I noticed [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4675618/an-alternate-3d-geometry-where-there-is-a-single-origin-where-parallel-lines-int). It seems like one where a non-mathematician is asking for help in "mathematizing" their question, which is how I'm understanding your post here. Maybe start saving off questions that exemplify the problem? These days you can create a list under your "Saves" specifically for just such questions. And I honestly do think specific examples make policy discussions better.

Comment: I agree with @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC's point that evidence would be useful here, and possibly more use of the [tag:applications] tag would help? This would allow the site to track these kinds of questions, and may solve the underlying problem by encourage users to act differently towards them.

Comment: I agree with user1729 that more focus on applications of mathematics could help. I am an economist, I answered here on MathSE to a question  about mathematics in economics, the question was hastlily  closed for 'lack of clarity', even if my quite long answer should have suggested that the question was clear to an economist.  A bit of patience would have been required.

Comment: My impression, from my experience on SE sites and long experience on other sites, is of too many people in moderation. They are not ‘professional’ moderators, they are not selected, but have moderation privileges only for their reputation, and nothing ensures that they know how to moderate a site. Many act according  to  subjective ideas of ‘policy’, hastily and erratically. The resulting  impression is often  a disordered, random moderation. Maybe  there should be more selected and skilled moderatos. I don’t know how, because I realize that the site is large and there are a lot of questions.

Comment: Maybe there could be more guidelines for moderators, including suggestions about how to behave about closing and deleting questions.

Comment: @BakerStreet - Are you considering everyone who has sufficient privileges to cast a "close" vote to be a moderator? Because that horde of people is the very core of the Stackexchange model and business plan, so I don't know that they're likely to drastically change that.

Comment: Yes, I mean that. I don't say that they can change, the moderation of the site is a core feature, but it has its drawbacks, compared  with sites that have only 'selected' moderators.  And my impression is that a not very 'professional' way of moderation can be the source  of some problems as pointed out by the OP. But something maybe can be done to improve moderation, for instance more written guidelines or 'elected' moderators guidance, I don't know. This is a problem specific of MathSE, other SE sites haven't so many people,  people with privileges are fewer and moderation is more 'regular'.

Comment: I have no solution, I made just an observation about a possible source of problems.

Comment: @BakerStreet - Yeah, Math.SE is definitely an odd duck among the stackexchange sites. It's just that I take them number of people with moderation duties/privileges as a given, so describing it as "too many" seemed a bit futile. But I agree that more written guidelines could help, hence my answer. And one thing I've noticed is that showing them once, initially, doesn't seem to help, so I followed the practice of others, by creating a pastable paragraph. I hope people at least give it a shot.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo The text you cited is so funny, I almost died reading [this](https://i.imgur.com/uPkSZ09.png). XD

Comment: For a fresh example, everybody who upvoted this question here would have likely voted to reopen [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4588802/roots-of-a-set-of-nonlinear-equations-ax-yz-b-1-ay-xz-b-2-az-xy-b), which the OP updated today, after 4+ months. No one did, though, which only reinforces @MJD's point that "*closure is a death sentence for the post*". This was clearly not homework after all this time, and just as clearly it is an applications question from someone seeking math help where they thought they would find qualified math help, only to be rebuffed without cause.

Comment: @MJD I actually don't think that the *core* issue is that close voters aren't being aware of closed posts. Only my experience but I've found that there are groups whose view on what's right and what's not are miles apart. Making reopening and closing easier doesn't make things easier when there isn't *consensus* at the bottom. It will probably lead to more close-open wars. Hence the comments on "inconsistency" of moderation as well. However, I do agree that forcing moderation will make users interact more. After many interactions, I have become far more "moderate" than I was once.

Comment: @dxiv As for the application of mathematics to problems  from non-math fields, may be some closers should be suggested to be more humble and cautious about other disciplines: “There are more things in Heaven and Earth, Than are dreamt of in your mathematics”. The translation in rigorous mathematical terms is not so obvious from the beginning (as Rodrigo says), but comes at the end of a process. History of mathematics teaches us that: maybe some enthusiast-closers would have closed Dirac speaking of his $\Delta$ or  Fourier about heat, who was accused, also by Lagrange, of lack of rigor.

Comment: @BakerStreet *"The owl of Minerva spreads its wings only with the coming of the dusk*" — Hegel

Comment: It just takes 5 random people to close a question, and voting to close is one of the easiest privileges to exercise. To my mind, this results in a lot of inappropriate closures and subsequent deletions.

Comment: @CheerfulParsnip I think better communication, as suggested in the answer, as well as promoting (good) use of the [Requests for Reopen & Undeletion Votes](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/34447/10513) is a good way to counter this. The review queue is *epically* long so I feel that helping existing users is better than altering the qualifications.

Comment: @user1729 this is actually related to my point. It takes almost no effort to vote to close. One just has to click without thinking. Actually helping a user to improve their question takes a lot more effort, so the incentives are skewed toward voting to close.

Comment: @CheerfulParsnip I agree - I guess my point is that this needs to be countered somehow, rather than just pointed at :-) [This also links to your name - I want to be positive about it, and being cheerful (as opposed to grumpy, or was that someone else?) is a good place to be!]

Answer (score 13):

Suggestion: You/we can make sure that such questions are tagged with the [applications](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/applications) tag, as suggested by @user1729.

Additionally, we can come up with some boilerplate comment, like

> Community: Note that this is a question about an [application](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/applications) of math, which is permitted. Please do not vote to close or delete just because it is not purely a math question. Feel free to use comments and questions to the OP to better define the mathematics of it, if you are
> so inclined.

Or for easier copy-pasting:

```
Community: Note that this is a question about an 
[application](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/applications) 
of math, which is permitted. Please do not vote to close or delete just 
because it is not purely a math question. Feel free to use comments and 
questions to the OP to better define the mathematics of it, if you are 
so inclined.
```

Rodrigo, would you be interested in "protecting" questions like these with such a comment?

Comment: I like this proposal, but I doubt that such a comment will have a noticeable effect on people voting to close or delete.

Comment: This is potentially interesting.  Alternatively, a link to this answer in a header would also be interesting.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo - I'm not sure what you mean by "in a header".

Comment: @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC [This question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33414/339790) has a header, for example.

Comment: I have not seen questions of this kind flooding the site in any way, and if any of them improve and become good questions then they're way, way more different and unique compared to the humdrum served up in general. Definitely, if someone left such a comment as above in good faith, that question shouldn't be closed.